# UnsupportedOperationException while executing Cypher Query in Java to Neo4j Server

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm query a Neo4j Server with the following Cypher nad it works fine:

```
GraphDatabaseService neo4j = new RestGraphDatabase("http://my.ip:7474/db/data");
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(
String myCypher = "START n = node(1234) RETURN n LIMIT 10;"
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(myCypher);
System.out.println(result);
```

If I change the first line of the query to `START n = node(*) RETURN n LIMIT 10;` I get this ugly exception **when I try to print the result**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.AbstractRemoteDatabase.getNodeManager(AbstractRemoteDatabase.java:144)
>       at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.getNodeManager(RestGraphDatabase.java:33)
>       at org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.(GlobalGraphOperations.java:39)
>       at org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.at(GlobalGraphOperations.java:51)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.GraphGlobalStartBuilder$$anonfun$createStartPipe$1.apply(GraphGlobalStartBuilder.scala:51)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.GraphGlobalStartBuilder$$anonfun$createStartPipe$1.apply(GraphGlobalStartBuilder.scala:51)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:38)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:37)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:200)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:200)
>       at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:200)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:45)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe.createResults(StartPipe.scala:37)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.MatchPipe.createResults(MatchPipe.scala:31)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.NamedPathPipe.createResults(NamedPathPipe.scala:26)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe.createResults(FilterPipe.scala:28)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe.createResults(ExtractPipe.scala:37)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.createResults(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:49)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe.createResults(ExtractPipe.scala:37)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ColumnFilterPipe.createResults(ColumnFilterPipe.scala:39)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.createResults(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:49)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe.createResults(ExtractPipe.scala:37)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ColumnFilterPipe.createResults(ColumnFilterPipe.scala:39)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:95)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:95)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.immutableResult(PipeExecutionResult.scala:37)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.iterator(PipeExecutionResult.scala:153)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:155)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.toString(Iterator.scala:1030)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.toString(Iterator.scala:333)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:185)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$addString$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:287)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:660)
>       at scala.Product$$anon$1.foreach(Product.scala:38)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:285)
>       at scala.Product$$anon$1.addString(Product.scala:38)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:263)
>       at scala.Product$$anon$1.mkString(Product.scala:38)
>       at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$._toString(ScalaRunTime.scala:175)
>       at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IteratorWrapper.toString(JavaConversions.scala:561)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
>       at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:771)

Also, things like `System.out.println(result.columns())` work fine and I can execute everything perfectly from the console... What's going on?

**EDIT:**

The query seems to return too fast, is there anything that I should do 'to make java wait' for a full response?

Comment: seems to be odd. what do you get if you execute the query in pure cypher console (via weadmin for example)?

Comment: from the console it works fine, I get 10 nodes back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that!

Use `new RestCypherQueryEngine(restGraphDb.getRestAPI())` instead, otherwise all your queries are run on the client and each database access goes over the network.

And make sure to use parameters in your queries.

Use:

```
QueryResult<Map<String, Object>> query(String statement, Map<String, Object> params)
```

Answer (score 0):

from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953423/1498109

i guess you are trying to convert an object/array to string at `System.out.println(result)`