# Java Neo4j Cypher query results in unsupportedException when node(*) is used vice node(1,2,3...)

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Given the following code:

```
public class Foo
{

     public void go(String relationship)
     {
             RestGraphDatabase rest = new RestGraphDatabase(
            prop.getProperty("address"), prop.getProperty("username"),
            prop.getProperty("password"));
             ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(rest,
            StringLogger.SYSTEM);
             ExecutionResult result = engine
                .execute("start n=node(7,8,9)  match(n)-[" + relationship
                        + "]->(x) return n,x,caution");    
                    scala.collection.Iterator<Node> nodes = result.columnAs("n");                
     }
}
```

The above works and allows me to iterate over my columns however:

```
public class Foo
{

     public void go(String relationship)
     {
             RestGraphDatabase rest = new RestGraphDatabase(
            prop.getProperty("address"), prop.getProperty("username"),
            prop.getProperty("password"));
             ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(rest,
            StringLogger.SYSTEM);
             ExecutionResult result = engine
                .execute("start n=node(*)  match(n)-[" + relationship
                        + "]->(x) return n,x,caution");    
                    scala.collection.Iterator<Node> nodes = result.columnAs("n");                
     }
}
```

Results in the iterator throwing an unsupported exception.  Is `node(*)` not syntactic sugar for listing out the values?  And if not how can I `node(*)` and iterate over it?

Stack:

> 2013-02-18 03:13:22.227+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: start n=node(*) 
>   match(n)-[caution]->(x) return n,x,caution List(n, x, caution)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException    at
>   org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.AbstractRemoteDatabase.getNodeManager(AbstractRemoteDatabase.java:136)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.getNodeManager(RestGraphDatabase.java:33)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.(GlobalGraphOperations.java:39)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.at(GlobalGraphOperations.java:51)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.GraphGlobalStartBuilder$$anonfun$createStartPipe$1.apply(GraphGlobalStartBuilder.scala:51)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.GraphGlobalStartBuilder$$anonfun$createStartPipe$1.apply(GraphGlobalStartBuilder.scala:51)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)    at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:36)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:139)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:256)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1156)

Comment: A tstorms said, never us a ExecutionEngine around a RestGraphDatabase, use RestCypherQueryEngine or RestAPIFacade.query().

Answer (score 0):

Use the RestCypherQueryEngine, see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811095/unsupportedoperationexception-while-executing-cypher-query-in-java-to-neo4j-serv). Seems there's a lot not supported if you look at the source: [AbstractRemoteDatabase](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/AbstractRemoteDatabase.java). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What is actually your goal with this query? This returns your whole graph?

If you want to do something with the data, do it **in** the query on the server side and not by pulling the data over the wire.

You also don't have an identifier named caution in your query.

```
start n=node(*)  
match(n)-[" + relationship + "]->(x) 
return n,x,caution
```

Comment: It was a test query as my graph only had 3 nodes (as I understand node(*) is almost never what is wanted).  I have since been able to fix this, I will post the solution this evening.  The majority of it is the conversation you and I have been having over the past few days in the google group.